# How to sense multiple key presses with Racket's `big-bang`

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm developing a simple Asteroids game in Racket and everything works well, except I want allow the player to move and fire at the same time.

Here are the control keys:

- Left / right to rotate
- Up / down to speed up, slow down
- Space to fire.

And my `on-key` handler:

```
(define (direct-ship w a-key)
  (define a-ship (world-ship w))
  (define a-direction
    (+ (ship-direction a-ship)
    (cond
      [(key=? a-key "left") -5]
      [(key=? a-key "right") 5]
      [else 0])))
  (define a-speed
    (+ (ship-speed a-ship)
       (cond
         [(key=? a-key "up") 1]
         [(key=? a-key "down") -1]
         [else 0])))
  (define bullets
    (cond
      [(key=? a-key " ") (cons (new-bullet a-ship) (world-bullets w))]
      [else (world-bullets w)]))

  (world (world-asteroids w)
         (ship (ship-pos a-ship) a-direction a-speed)
         bullets
         (world-score w)))
```

Given the signature of this proc it makes sense to me that it'll only handle a single char at a time. So maybe I need to use a different handler? Or different keys?

See the full source on github:
https://github.com/ericclack/racket-examples/blob/master/asteroids4.rkt

Comment: New working code here: https://github.com/ericclack/racket-examples/blob/master/asteroids5.rkt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `on-key` handler is only called for one key at a time. Even if you are able to press, say, right arrow and up arrow at the exact same time, `on-key` will be called twice.

One way to handle this is for each key to store information in a global table on whether the key is up or down. Given such a table you can use it in `on-key` to check the state of keys other than the one currently being handled.

The following are snippets from a Space Invaders clone. First the global keyboard table.

```
;;; Keyboard
; The keyboard state is kept in a hash table. 
; Use key-down? to find out, whether a key is pressed or not.
(define the-keyboard (make-hasheq))
(define (key-down! k) (hash-set! the-keyboard k #t))
(define (key-up! k)   (hash-set! the-keyboard k #f))
(define (key-down? k) (hash-ref  the-keyboard k #f))
```

Then the handling of events - which due to the context were done without `big-bang`, but it is idea that matters here.

```
;;; Canvas
; Key events sent to the canvas updates the information in the-keyboard.
; Paint events calls draw-world. To prevent flicker we suspend flushing
; while drawing commences.
(define game-canvas%
  (class canvas%
    (define/override (on-event e) ; mouse events
      'ignore)
    (define/override (on-char e)  ; key event
      (define key     (send e get-key-code))
      (define release (send e get-key-release-code))
      (when (eq? release 'press)  ; key down?
        (key-down! key))
      (when (eq? key 'release)    ; key up?
        (key-up! release)
        (when (eq? release #\space)
          (play-sound "shoot.mp3" #t))))
    (define/override (on-paint)   ; repaint (exposed or resized)
      (define dc (send this get-dc))
      (send this suspend-flush)
      (send dc clear)
      (draw-world the-world dc)
      (send this resume-flush))
    (super-new)))
```

As you can see the key event handler does nothing more than store whether keys are up and down (and for some odd reason play the "shoot.mp3" sample). So where do the player actually move (according to the arrow keys)?

The actual movement is handled in `on-tick` (or the equivalent thereof).
Handling movement in `on-tick` ensures that the player doesn't move an extra distance when keys are pressed.

Comment: Consider using `hash-set` instead of mutating in this answer to be more inline with the principles of HtDP/`big-bang`.